# What is a word describing a “long-lasting memory” of someone?

Tags: single-word-requests

What noun in English is the best for describing the essence of a long-lasting memory that some person (e.g. spiritual leader or famous musician) leaves after himself? Is it *perpetuation*, or *commemoration*, or maybe *heritage*, or *record*, or some other word? I know the word *notoriety* meaning ill fame, but I don’t know any word for the good one.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Legacy**

> something transmitted by or received from an ancestor or predecessor or from the past ([m-w](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/legacy))

"To leave a legacy" is a common way to refer to an individual having a great impact on future generations.  Unqualified it connotes a positive impact, but it can be modified with a negative term (like "legacy of conflict") to refer to a negative impact as well.

Answer (score 4):

**"immortality"** comes to mind. In addition to "the quality or state of being immortal" it also means:

> enduring fame. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/immortality), "lasting fame" [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immortality), the quality or state of someone that will never be forgotten.

- He found immortality through his films.
- Some people want to achieve immortality through their works.

Answer (score 4):

**"indelible"** meaning something that cannot be erased (by the passage of time.)

A synonom would be **"ineffaceable"**  (edit - which is unrelated to "ineffable" .)

Comment: No, *ineffable* is a separate word; but *indelible* is an excellent thought. All three are adjectives, and *indelible* and *ineffaceable* might modify *memory* to the proper effect.

Comment: You are correct - I have learned something, my apologies.    Is it permitted to edit my answer and remove the incorrect details?  Not sure of the board's etiquette.

Comment: @Criggie Yes, please do; that's perfectly fine.

Comment: And erring and learning, when they travel together, need no apology.

Answer (score -2):

*Photographic memory* or  *eidetic memory* is the word you're looking for.

Comment: The Q asked: *What noun in English is the best for describing the essence of* ***a long-lasting memory*** that some person ***leaves*** *after himself?* It is nothing to do with the ability to memorize names, lists, details or events.